# Как передвигать панель вместе с label?

Tags: c#, winforms

На форму вешаю компонент "Panel" кидаю на панель label.

Для передвижения панели без бордера кидаю код в `MouseDown`:

---

```
private void Panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Panel1.Capture = false;
   var m = Message.Create(Handle, 0xa1, new IntPtr(2), IntPtr.Zero);
   WndProc(ref m);
}
```

---

Так передвигается просто панель, а как сделать чтобы ещё при зажатие на label панель передвигалась?

Comment: Сделай label дочерним элементом панели

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта.

1. Все дочерние контролы на этой панели подписать на событие и аналогично передвигать панель.

   Чуть переделаем обработчик события, чтобы один метод можно было использовать для всех контролов:

   ```
   private void Controls_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       var control = (Control)sender;
       control.Capture = false;

       var m = Message.Create(panel1.Handle, 0xa1, new IntPtr(2), IntPtr.Zero);
       WndProc(ref m);
   }
   ```

   Подписываем на это событие как саму панель, так и все контролы, расположенные на ней:

   ```
   panel1.MouseDown += Controls_MouseDown;
   label2.MouseDown += Controls_MouseDown;
   ```

   Естественно, это можно сделать в дизайнере, выбирая нужное событие в окне свойств (Properties).

2. Сделать `Label` (и все другие используемые контролы) на этой панели прозрачным для кликов.

   ```
   public class HitTransparentLabel : Label
   {
       protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
       {
           const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
           const int HTTRANSPARENT = -1;

           if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
               m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTRANSPARENT;
           else
               base.WndProc(ref m);
       }
   }
   ```

   Добавляем код этого класса в проект, компилируем. После этого в панели инструментов (Toolbox) появится новый компонент. Используем его так же, как обычный `Label`. Ну, почти так же: не забываем, что он прозрачный для кликов.

   Чтобы контрол можно было перетаскивать мышкой в режиме дизайнера, нужно добавить проверку:

   ```
   if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && !DesignMode)
   ```

   При ручном создании просто пишем `new HitTransparentLabel` вместо `new Label`.

Comment: 2-ое как вызывать?. А как подписать событие?

Comment: @ArteS - дополнил ответ.

Comment: Работает как надо, спасибо большое)